# How to save measurement points for big area in database, so it can be selected quick?

Tags: mysql

### The issue

I am not sure how to save measurement data for big areas so that it can be quickly retrieved from a database.

### Details

#### Measurement data

The measurements data consists of:

- Longitude degree
- Latitude degree
- Signal power
- Transmitter ID

Each area could potentially have multiple transmitters.

The data that describes the signal from a single transmitter is stored in a file. From one file I create about 2 million rows (points with signal power). All the data should be saved due to signal strength variations.

For a table with only one transmitter, selecting points that are +/- *x* meters in any common relative direction (←↑→↓) from a specific point (longitude, latitude) takes approximately 0.5 s.

### The Problem

I have to show a signal for about 65000 points in a single query, so it will take pretty long (65000x05 s.), to calculate it.

### What I've done

I decided to save every transmitter into a separate table. In the main table I save only the coordinates from left lower corner and right upper corner (this way I can determine which transmitters table consists of points next to a point and I can select the data from that specific table). The problem, however, still exists as my table still has around 2 million rows.

The main table, where all transmitters are saved:

```
╔════╦═══════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╦════════════════════════╦════════════════════════╗
║ id ║ left_lower_corner_lon ║ left_lower_corner_lat ║ right_upper_corner_lon ║ right_upper_corner_lat ║
╠════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬════════════════════════╬════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ 12                    ║                    48 ║                     13 ║                     49 ║
║  2 ║ 12.5                  ║                    48 ║                     14 ║                     50 ║
╚════╩═══════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╩════════════════════════╩════════════════════════╝
```

and now tables for single transmitters (i.e. transmitter_1):

```
╔═════════╦═════════╦═══════════╗
║   lon   ║   lat   ║    sig    ║
╠═════════╬═════════╬═══════════╣
║ 48,0004 ║ 12,0002 ║ -123,0000 ║
║ 48,0004 ║ 12,0003 ║ 124,0000  ║
╚═════════╩═════════╩═══════════╝
```

Now in order to get signals from all transmitters for a specific point, first I select the id of the trasmitter and after that i look in the next table for the nearest point. But it takes too long already for only one point (0.5 s.).

### My query

```
#in order to test, im using these variables:
SET @_lon = 13.729520117164848;
SET @_lat = 51.126581079972624;

SELECT lat, lon, sig, SQRT(
    POW(69.1 * (lat - @_lat), 2) +
    POW(69.1 * (@_lon - lon) * COS(lat / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
FROM (SELECT * FROM `transmitter_1` WHERE (lon <= @_lon+0.00009 && lon >= @_lon-0.00009 && lat <= @_lat+0.00009 && lat >= 0.00009)) AS nearest_points
HAVING distance < 25  ORDER BY distance LIMIt 1;
```

### My ideas

I believe that I create more tables for a single transmitter and again save coordinates for 2 corners.

1. How can find a compromise between the number of rows in a table and the performance time from php?
2. Should I maybe create the whole chain in my sql (as function) and not in php? Will I spare this way more than 0.005s for one point?

   - Select transmitter table that consists of a point
   - Then selecting a part table for a transmitter that consists of this point
   - And finally selecting the nearest point as MySQL function

Comment: Would you be able to give us a few rows examples of your database (you can change numbers, but that way we have a general idea of the content/structure). I'm also not quite sure how you're retrieving these fields, but is the table/are the tables indexed properly?

Comment: I dont really use indexes. I have now 3 tables, I will edit my aswer to show you, how these tables look like.

Comment: Do you have any code samples for the query you are currently using? Also, how many transmitters in total do you have right now and how many do you foresee in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Any time you enter a field into a "where", be sure that field is indexed. You can also experiment with multi-field indexes (if you always search by lon and lat, put in an index with both fields).

That's where the speed comes from. I've seen queries that took hours reduced (literally) to seconds with proper indexing.

On tables with millions of records, you can also experiment with segmenting the data by using separate tables, separate databases and also look at partitioning the data within the databases.

But before you go there: Index.

Run your query. Index lon and then index lat (just index, not unique or primary). Run it again. Then index long and lat together in the same index and run the query one more time. Compare your times. You should see a significant reduction in response time.